# NoClassDefFoundError when using system scope

Tags: java, maven

I am currently facing and issue when using Maven with NetBeans 7.1 - I have included a lib that I can't place into a Maven repository in the System scope. It looks something like the following:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>FBTM</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/FBTM-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

The IDE seems to pick up this dependency fine, as it shows in Dependencies folder (Project view) and I am able to view the jar contents. I can also import classes from the jar without any issues.

However, when I attempt to run my project (and the runtime has any of the classes in use) I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` for the class in question. It can be any class.

Stacktrace:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/company/otaupdate/sim/commands/Select
    at com.company.fbtranslationlibrary.mc.scripts.UserData$1.<init>(UserData.java:30)
    at com.company.fbtranslationlibrary.mc.scripts.UserData.<init>(UserData.java:28)
    at com.company.fbtranslationlibrary.mc.MS.get_profile_script(MuscadeScript.java:80)
    at com.company.fbtranslationlibrary.mc.MS.access$300(MS.java:16)`

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Problems resolving `${project.basedir}`, maybe?

Comment: scope:system feels wrong, do you need it to be like that? Or can you try with none (or compile).

Comment: What is the exact exception message/stack trace?

Comment: I'd like to have this library in a Maven dependency, but due to over complication of the library I can't right now. 

I need to be able to have the jar resolved to the project without it being in a M2 repo; can this be done with a scope other than System? 

@m0skit0: How can I set the project.basedir variable? - NetBeans seems to resolve it fine.

Comment: Probably because it's a NetBeans variable... Either substitute with real path or use another variable and define it.

Comment: OKay cheers I will do that. @Attila: Question updated with ST.

Comment: @m0skit0: Using a real path lead to the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

For system scope:

[Maven Doc](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) says:

> system
>
> This scope is similar to provided except that you have to
>   provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always
>   available and is not looked up in a repository.

Your IDE provides the jar somehow. But when running *you* need to provide it.

Try with the default scope (that is no scope tag at all).

edit:
If you want maven to keep the system scope, you need to provide the jar runtime via the classpath.

Comment: Using no scope tag leads to the systemPath tag being invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the NetBeans application runner is not smart enough to put this JAR file on the execution classpath.

Why don't you add the JAR and POM files for this dependency to your **local** repository?  Then you can use a regular dependency.

Alternatively, see if there's a way to tweak the runtime classpath for the NetBeans application launcher for this application.  (I'm not sure I'm using the right terminology here ... I'm an Eclipse person.)

Comment: I can only provide the JAR for this dependency, as it's not an m2 project. Would this suffice?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by creating the following build.xml for the project:

```
    <!-- make the repo dir -->
    <mkdir dir="${m2.home}" />

    <!-- copy libs -->
    <copy  todir="${m2.home}">
        <fileset dir="dist"/>
    </copy>

    <!-- copy pom -->
    <copy  todir="${m2.home}">
        <fileset dir="pom"/>
         <mapper>
            <mapper type="regexp" 
                from="pom.xml" to="${m2.app.name}-${m2.app.ver}.pom" />
        </mapper>
    </copy>

    <!-- use naming policy -->
    <copy  todir="${m2.home}">
        <fileset dir="dist"/>
        <mapper>
            <mapper type="regexp" 
                from="${m2.app.name}.jar" to="${m2.app.name}-${m2.app.ver}.jar" />
        </mapper>
    </copy>

    <!-- remove unnecessiary files -->
    <delete>
    <fileset dir="${m2.home}">
        <include name="${m2.app.name}.jar"/>
        <include name="README.TXT"/>
    </fileset>
    </delete>
</target>
```

I also had to manually create a pom.xml file for the project, which I copy over to the local repository using the same naming conventions. It's not the best solution possible, but works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid system scope and use workaround noted in

http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2014/06/10/maven-include-system-scope-dependency-in-maven-assembly-plugin/